# Move to new Activity on button click using Kotlin, passing no information, in as simple code as possible

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

In Android Studio, I'm looking for instructions on how to move from MainActivity to SecondActivity using a button click in the simplest possible method. All the instructions I can find for this are either for Java, too old, or are too complicated (i.e. involve passing data or displaying messages on the second activity). I'm literally just looking for the Android equivalent of hyperlinking to a different "page"/activity in web design.

Android's own documentation contains a complicated solution that involves passing data and displaying messages: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity(){

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        button.setOnClickListener { 
            
            startActivity(Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java))
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for!